# How to use Bootstrapthemes in Domino?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-domino

I´m currenlty working on an project for University. We did some work with Domino already. Our tutor asked us to "apply one of the existing bootstrap themes" to our app. 
He gave us some short Instructions:

-

1. Uploading the App to our development Server. (We did this with
   Application -> New Copy -> Our Server
2. Application -> Sign Design ->okay
3. Go to  xsp.properties and apply Theme Bootstrap 3

We tried with the two Override options and without them but when previewing some XPages, they still look the same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk2YX.png)

We would be really happy for any helping information, tutorial or other stuff where we can learn how to do this. Since we have never worked with domino bevore this we are pretty noobish. So sorry if there are any Infomations missing & thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you building your app in Domino using XPages? The theme section (in xsp.properties) is for XPages apps only.

Comment: Yes we are fully building it it in Domino with XPages

Comment: Great. I have added the 'xpages' tag to your question

Comment: Okay thank you :-)

Comment: I used to maintain a site called bootstrap4xpages.com that had examples on using Bootstrap in XPages. The domain isn't available anymore, but the content can still be viewed here: https://demo.linqed.eu/bs4xp/site.nsf. Hope that helps!

Comment: From the first view this looks perfect. I´ll check it out asap. Thanks